# Fixing Sumproduct or Query to work in GOOGLE sheets to count 2 criteria in 2 different size arrays.

Tags: google-sheets, counting

For my current research I want to find out how many surveys are filled out for a specific condition and at what month interval they were filled out.
i.e. Patients may have multiple conditions (dozens of different conditions are possible to choose from) that I want to survey and may appear in C2:G7. 
If I look at Dizziness, how many surveys contain 'dizziness' and were taken at around the 1 month interval? 2 month interval? 6 month interval? For the example, my output for dizziness at 1 month should be a count of 2.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zc3tn34OoW-4ZAeGR6qkz1H0MymqYWFOVdptOMnJ5ro/edit?usp=sharing

So far I've tried COUNTIFS, but it doesn't work with different size arrays; at least to my knowledge. I've also tried SUMPRODUCT
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:H7=B4)*--(I2:I7<2)) which works in Excel, but not Googlesheets. (NOTE: <2 for 1month because some patients may take it at 1.25 or 1.5 months.

I'm looking at Query, but am not familiar enough with SQL language and format to get it to work. So far I have
=QUERY(C2:I7, "select Countif(A) where C E G =C11 And I=2")

I don't know which function would be best to use and how to make it work. Help please?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding a formula in Column J that aggregates your data per row entry. You can the use that to search for an entry that has the corresponding condition.

In column J – "Joined Values". This formula needs to be copy/pasted down for all of your data.

```
=JOIN(", ", C2:G2)
```

Then you can use [`=FILTER()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) to select the values that you need. This returns an array of the months where "Dizziness" was present.

```
=FILTER(I2:I7, ISNUMBER(FIND(C11, J2:J7)))
```

Finally, you can use that Filter formula directly in your other formulas. This will return `2` for dizziness at 1 month.

```
=COUNTIF(FILTER(I2:I7, ISNUMBER(FIND(C11, J2:J7))), "<2")
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Indirect does not work with Sumproduct.

[https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/9ibr0SsqCnsqCns](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/9ibr0SsqCns)